# Namespacing for a relationship loop breaks scope?

Tags: channel-entries, templates, relationships, channel

I have a "videos" channel that has a one-to-one relationship with a "person" and a one-to-many relationship with other videos in the same channel. I am trying to display the information about the person and the related videos with a template like this.

```
<Videos>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="videos"}
    <Video>
        <Subject>{person:title}</Subject>
        <Affiliation>{person:affiliation}</Affiliation>
        <RelatedVideos>
            {related}
            <VideoId>{related:person:title}</VideoId>
            {/related}
        </RelatedVideos>
    </Video>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</Videos>
```

This results in:

```
<Videos>
    <Video>
        <Subject/>
        <Affiliation/>
        <RelatedVideos>
            <VideoId>title 1</VideoId>
            <VideoId>title 1</VideoId>
            <VideoId>title 1</VideoId>
        </RelatedVideos>
    </Video>
</Videos>
```

Note the empty `<Subject/>` and `<Affiliation/>`.

However if I change the template to exclude the related video person:

```
<Videos>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="videos"}
    <Video>
        <Subject>{person:title}</Subject>
        <Affiliation>{person:affiliation}</Affiliation>
        <RelatedVideos>
            {related}
            {!-- <VideoId>{related:person:title}</VideoId> --}
            {/related}
        </RelatedVideos>
    </Video>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</Videos>
```

I get this:

```
<Videos>
    <Video>
        <Subject>title 1</Subject>
        <Affiliation>affiliation 1</Affiliation>
        <RelatedVideos></RelatedVideos>
    </Video>
</Videos>
```

It seems I can get either the person related to my entry, or the person related to the other entries related to this entry. How can I get both?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused as to your channel and channel fields setup, but think you might be missing something if I am understanding.

Since `person` is a relationship field then you should add the `person` tag pair.

```
<Videos>
    {exp:channel:entries channel="videos"}
    <Video>
        {person}
        <Subject>{person:title}</Subject>
        <Affiliation>{person:affiliation}</Affiliation>
        {/person}
        <RelatedVideos>
            {related}
            <VideoId>{related:person:title}</VideoId>
            {/related}
        </RelatedVideos>
    </Video>
    {/exp:channel:entries}
</Videos>
```

Comment: I actually do have that tag pair in my template, but the behavior seems to be the same with or without it, so I removed it in my question to reduce it to the smallest possible example.

The video has a one-to-one relationship to a person.
The video also has a one-to-many relationship with other videos.

Things break if I try to show the title of the person related to the child video that's related to the parent video.

If I change the commented line to ```{related:title}```, the related video title shows fine. But I want the person title, which seems to cause trouble.